# How to get google+ 's public content (posts) to my website

Tags: google-plus

I want to add Google +'s public posts (content) to my website.
I'm not talking about embedding The content.

It should be like Facebook's Like Box.(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/)

Is it possible in Google Plus or i have to use hard coded embedded plugin ?

Thanks in advance.

I was fail to Attach image because of lack of "respect" but Hope i'm clear with my question.

Comment: You can still link to an image that you host elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I think you might be asking for the [Google+ Badges](https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/), which have similar capabilities to the Face Book Like Box. If your site has its own Page profile (or maybe create a page for your site), you'd use that type of badge. If its you as an individual that you want to display, you'd use the Person badge.